# Algorithm for finding all combinations of (x,y,z,j) that satisfy w+x = y+j, where w,x,y,j are integers between -N...N inclusive

Tags: algorithm, language-agnostic, permutation, combinatorics

I'm working on a problem that requires an array (dA[j], j=-N..N) to be calculated from the values of another array (A[i], i=-N..N) based on a conservation of momentum rule (x+y=z+j).   This means that for a given index j for all the valid combinations of (x,y,z) I calculate A[x]A[y]A[z].  dA[j] is equal to the sum of these values.

I'm currently precomputing the valid indices for each dA[j] by looping x=-N...+N,y=-N...+N and calculating z=x+y-j and storing the indices if abs(z) <= N.

Is there a more efficient method of computing this?

The reason I ask is that in future I'd like to also be able to efficiently find for each dA[j] all the terms that have a specific A[i].  Essentially to be able to compute the Jacobian of dA[j] with respect to dA[i].

**Update**

For the sake of completeness I figured out a way of doing this without any if statements: if you parametrize the equation x+y=z+j given that j is a constant you get the equation for a plane.  The constraint that x,y,z need to be integers between -N..N create boundaries on this plane.  The points that define this boundary are functions of N and j.  So all you have to do is loop over your parametrized variables (s,t) within these boundaries and you'll generate all the valid points by using the vectors defined by the plane (s*u + t*v + j*[0,0,1]).

For example, if you choose u=[1,0,-1] and v=[0,1,1] all the valid solutions for every value of j are bounded by a 6 sided polygon with points (-N,-N),(-N,-j),(j,N),(N,N),(N,-j), and (j,-N).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So for each `j`, you go through all `(2N)^2` combinations to find the correct `x's` and `y's` such that `x+y= z+j`; the running time of your application (per `j`) is `O(N^2)`. I don't think your current idea is bad (and after playing with some pseudocode for this, I couldn't improve it significantly). I would like to note that once you've picked a `j` and a `z`, there is *at most* `2N` choices for `x's` and `y's`. So overall, the best algorithm would still complete in `O(N^2)`.

But consider the following improvement by a factor of 2 (for the overall program, not per `j`): if `z+j= x+y`, then `(-z)+(-j)= (-x)+(-y)` also.

Comment: Thanks, I've been told the number of combinations for a particular dA[j] is 3(N^2)+3N-(j^2)+1 - maximum at j=0 and minimum at j=+N,-N.

Comment: Yep, that looks about right. No tremendous improvement is possible.

Comment: (If my answer seems adequate to you, don't forget to select it and the question wouldn't be left open.)